# "Back to the parent activity" button stopped working in Android application

Tags: android, android-activity, parent-child

I have to fix a bug: clicking (tapping on) the "back to the parent activity" arrow does not bring back to the parent activity in Android application.

The activity is defined in the manifest as

```
    <activity
        android:name=".WorkHistory"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
        android:parentActivityName=".Progress" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.au.ontime.Progress" />
    </activity>
```

and launched from the `com.au.ontime.Progress` activity like

```
        intent = new Intent(Progress.this, WorkHistory.class);
        if (timeLine.onTheClock()) {
            intent.putExtra("activeSince", timeLine.getLastClockin());
            intent.putExtra("active", timeLine.getActive());
        }
        startActivity(intent);
```

The activity does not have any code to call `finish()`. It was always closed by tapping on the arrow on the top left and this worked before. The activity otherwise starts and executes normally, without error messages in the logs. The back arrow is visible just not functional. There are other child activities in for this parent; these are defined in a similar way and works.

The device is Nexus 5, running Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

The overridden `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` was returning boolean value true also for the unrecognized values of `item.getItemId()`. I was wrongly assumed that the method will only be called with my menu items but it seems part of some more complex processing mechanism. Esoteric values may be passed a parameter and false must be returned by the method to allow OS to handle them.